# text-align not working specific way

Tags: css, html

I want to know why `.sisa span{}` is not working but `.sisa,span{}` is working ?
doesnt it mean that without the comma you are simply selecting all spans within that class ? so it should also work ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> html5</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
<style>

div.sisa{
    width: 515px;
    height: 230px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
    background-color: #adfab7;
}
.sisa span{
text-align:center;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form >
  <div class="sisa">
<span>Esim. postinumero tai kunta </span>

   </div> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @dippas it's not about the difference between having space or not, it's about the difference between having a space or a  `,`

Answer (score 1):

When used with space your selector is targeting and centring the content of `span` but it's an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) that fits its content so there is nothing to center. When used with `,` you are applying the center to the div (so you center its content including the `span` element) **and** applying the center to the `span` but it's useless.

So you only need this:

```css
div.sisa {
  width: 515px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #73AD21;
  background-color: #adfab7;
}

.sisa {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="sisa">
    <span>Esim. postinumero tai kunta </span>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: in your way its targeting everything inside  'sisa' class but i want to target just that text which is inside 'span' and not more

Comment: @waleedd32 but the span is an inline element, you can do nothing inside it .. check the update, I added a border to see the difference

Comment: i fixed it by puting  span as a block then it worked

Comment: @waleedd32 in this case better use div than span ;) since div is already a block element